# capistrano deployment precompile reduce the precompile time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compilation, capistrano, bundler

I am trying to deploy with capistrano version 3.

I have staging and production servers, after deploying to production, I manually do precompile  in the server.

assets compilation takes a lot of time nearly more than half an hour, is there a way to reduce the precompile time, like not compiling unwanted/unchanged files

Comment: Do the precompile locally then deploy to the server.

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson : I use git to mantain the project, i don want to push compiled assets to git, and i use capistrano for deployment.

Comment: I have used the following: cap v2 : https://gist.github.com/olegykz/4079213

Answer (score 0):

[Turbo sprockets gem](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) may be of some help.
It basically only compiles those files which have changed and not everything, if you don't want that you probably want to know which assets compilation is actually taking time by going through sprockets logs.